# save Python script with formatting - special characters

Tags: python, pygments

I use pygmentize to save my Python script as rtf file (with propoer colors depends on keywords in syntax). 
Unfortunatelly program substitute special characters (ą,ę,ź,ć,ó) with strange symbols.
Is there any option to set proper code page?
Alternatively - is there any other tool which can proceed this operation properly?

If answer for both question is no - how I should automatically remove all special characters from Python script?

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the [`encoding` option](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/#a-note-on-encodings) so pygmentize will use the actual encoding of your source file? If you don't, it defaults to `latin-1` which doesn't contain the characters you quoted.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer - you wrote "encoding of source code". I didn't set encoding in my source code (well, I must admit that I use pygmentize to color also R! scripts, so i suppose that even if I set it, it will doesn't work properly).

Comment: But you did --- although maybe not explicitly. Check the encoding settings of your editor and use that.

Comment: @Mateusz: The safest bet (generally) would be to use `utf-8` as your source encoding (which you need to tell your editor and (unless you're on Python 3) also your Python interpreter by inserting the line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your script). A decent editor can change the encoding of a source file for you. If you use `utf-8`, you're future-proof.